# Sharepoint isn't automatically creating my path to CDN

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, sharepoint-on-prem, 2019, cdn

I've created an SPFx Webpart and uploaded it to my app catalog, however it just says , and once I add my webpart to a page it throws the errors in the screenshot I'm attaching, because it's unable to access the compiled files.[image]

I've created plenty of webparts in the past and never encountered this issue, so I'm wondering if something is wrong with my project structure or if maybe something changed with the tenant. I'm on sharepoint 2019 on premise. Let me know if you need any other information to assist.